# ¿Como contar las columnas que fueron actualizadas en un trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, trigger

Tengo la siguiente tabla llamada *Peliculas*:

```
(id int, nombre varchar(50), genero varchar (50), clasificacion char(1), año int)
```

---

Tengo este *trigger* para validar que solo se pueda actualizar un campo a la vez de dicha tabla.

¿Habría alguna forma de optimizar este código para no utilizar tantos if?

Supongamos que el día de mañana tengo una tabla de 40 columnas.

```
create trigger tr_peliculasactulizacion on peliculas for update
as 
begin
    declare @conta int=0
    if update(id)
        select @conta+=1
    if update (nombre)
        select @conta+=1
    if update (genero)
        select @conta+=1
    if update(clasificacion)
        select @conta+=1
    if update(año)
        select @conta+=1
    if @conta>1
    begin
        rollback tran
        raiserror ('solo se puede actualizar un campo a la vez', 16, 1);
    end 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Si dispones de SQL Server 2008 o superior puedes usar la función [`COLUMNS_UPDATED()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/columns-updated-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) la cual retorna un `VARBINARY` que no es más que una máscara de bits, dónde cada bit en 1 representa en orden la columna que ha sido actualizada, es decir `1010` representa que se ha actualizada la columna 1 y 2 de una tabla de cuatro columnas. Para contar cuantos bits en `on` tenemos (la cantidad de columnas actualizadas) podemos hacer algo como esto:

```
create trigger tr_peliculasactulizacion on peliculas for update
as 
begin

    DECLARE @Binary VARBINARY = COLUMNS_UPDATED()
    DECLARE @C  INT  = 0

    WHILE @Binary > 0 
      SELECT @C = @C + (@Binary % 2),  
        @Binary = @Binary /2

    IF @C > 1
    begin
            rollback tran
            raiserror ('solo se puede actualizar un campo a la vez', 16, 1);
    end 
end
```